# Nuxt3 call openapi requests

Tags: server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I'm in the process of migrating an existing vue codebase to Nuxt3.

The existing codebase is using OpenApi to generate it's client code and access REST endpoints. The endpoints are called in separate stores.

Now I'm wondering if this approach makes good use of Nuxt'SSR functionality.
If my OpenAPI calls are called on the frontend side, then I would not make use of SSR.

Can anyone give me a bit technical information on how Nuxt3 is handling this?

Thank you